# Matching start and end of line with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the followig text in `/tmp/text`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

telnet> show counter
5737

telnet> exit
```

and trying to get the number `5737` that come alone in the line, and matches `^[0-9]*$` in regex. There's my sed

```
cat /tmp/text | sed -En 's/(^[0-9]*$)/\1/p'
```

but it matches nothing, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Try using 's/(^[0-9]+$)/\1/p' or you'll match empty lines.

Comment: Yes I missed that, that removes empty lines but doesn't match the numbers

Comment: That's odd, since it works for me with the exact same command. Could you have any weird line breaks in that file? You never know with telnet...

Comment: How to know if there's any special characters that confuse the regex  ?

Answer (score 1):

sed-expression looks fine to me. Telnet might output (probably invisible) ^M-newlines which cause your expression not to work. You might try

```
cat /tmp/text | sed -En 's/(^[0-9]+(^M)?$)/\1/p'
```

Whereas the ^M is created by pressing Ctrl+V and then Ctrl+M. That's the only explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '/telnet> show counter/{l=1;next}l==1{print;exit}' file
```

maybe you are doing the things the wrong way, is this command is what you expect ? :

```
nc 127.0.0.1 <YOUR_OWN_PORT> <<< 'show counter'
```

(using [nc](/questions/tagged/nc))

Comment: Actually I'm passing commands through telnet, `nc` doesn't work for me, anyway I've saved the output in a file so I can do some test without executing commands. About the solution you proposed it works fine, but I still need to know what's wrong in my sed expression and why it didn't match the numbers line

Answer (score 0):

This would be enough for your case.

```
$ sed -n '/^[0-9]\+$/p' file
5737
```

It just print the lines which has one or more digits. Because you input file contain blank lines, `sed -n '/^[0-9]*$/p' file` would print also the blank lines. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times and `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.